# Unable to access DialogFragment.....Any extra library i miss on it?

Tags: android

I am beginner on android and i would like to know what am i missing from the picture ? Anyone can help ?

The type or namespace name 'Dialog Fragment' could not be found (Are u missing a using directive or an assembly reference)

### Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Please don't post only screenshots of code, XML, or logcat output. Please post all text as text.

Comment: I am sorry, this is my first time at here and i edited my post.

Comment: You're extending DialogFragment, but you don't include it in your 'using' lines. Perhaps you need to import it?

Comment: Hi Jox,what namespace should i import ?

Answer (score 0):

i found out the solution. I resolved this through Tools->Android->Android SDK Manager ->Extras Folder -> Install (Android Support Repository)